# Sources for post quantum cryptography

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography

I already have experience with quantum computing and the mathematics behind it. I also know the quantum cryptography side e.g. BB84, etc.

I now want to move on to *post-quantum cryptography* and am therefore looking for suitable sources. Favored here is primary literature in the form of books, however there doesn't seem to be much here (PQC by Bernstein seems to be more or less the only book here). I am also looking for good lecture notes, such as slides and scripts on the subject.

If anyone here has any good recommendations, it would help me a lot. Thanks a lot for upcoming answers!

Comment: Even Bernstein's (also includes Buchmann as co-editor)  book [Springer-Verlag , 2009, 246 pages] is a collection of chapters, not a traditional book. This is because the field is relatively young.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tanja Lange has a course on post quantum cryptography https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCatHl2XgG1S3Vw4KD8IFnPQ